# How to get css class name using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, css-selectors

I am new in selenium testing. I want to get the css class name using selenium. I am using eclipse and Java for development.

```
<table >
<tr class="odd"><td>Odd row</td></tr>
<tr class="even"><td>Even row</td></tr>
<tr class="odd"><td>Odd row2</td></tr>
<tr class="even"><td>Even row2</td></tr>       
</table>
```

Is there any way to get the class name 'odd' or 'even' using selenium?  I

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can use `getAttribute(attributeLocator)` function for the your requirement.

```
 selenium.getAttribute(//xpath@class);
```

Specify the Xpath of the element for which you require to know the class of.

Thanks.

Answer (score 80):

From a `WebElement` you can use the `getAttribute` method like this:

```
element.getAttribute("class")
```

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing depending on eclipse or java, in fact it is more about location strategy.
If you want to access specific tr element with/without css class you can use
css locator:

`css=tr:nth(indx_base_0)`

nth row with class

`css=tr.odd:nth(indx_base_0)`

first row with class odd

`css=tr.odd`

Using xpath:

```
//tr[index_base_1]
```

first row with class odd

```
//tr[@class='odd']
```

nth row with class odd

```
//tr[@class='odd'][index_base_1]
```

Here are some [useful examples](http://blog.infostretch.com/?p=1101)

Answer (score 5):

In context of the code snippet, say you want to get the class "odd" for the first row in the table.
You can follow the below steps:
**(Note:- Assuming there is one table in your webpage)**

1- **Get the element first:**

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tr[1]"));
```

The above code uses the xpath to get the element, i.e., the first row of the table.

2- **Then, get the attribute "class" of the element using "getAttribute" method:**

```
String class_name = ele.getAttribute("class");
```

The above code will fetch the "class" name of the related element and assign it to the String variable "class_name" for further use

Similarly, for getting "even" class, which is the attribute for fourth row of table , you can use the below code:

```
ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tr[4]"));
class_name = ele.getAttribute("class");
```

Answer (score 1):

If CSS is your requirement, and in the absence of additional/differentiating element attributes, try the following (in the example, I have used simple text assertions):

```
assertEquals(selenium.getText("css=tr.odd > td"), "Odd row");
assertEquals(selenium.getText("css=tr.even > td"), "Even row");
assertEquals(selenium.getText("//tr[3]/td"), "Odd row2");
assertEquals(selenium.getText("//tr[4]/td"), "Even row2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the CSS class name using Selenium using C#:

```
string _className;
IWebElement _ele = _driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("Xpath of Element"));
_className = _ele.GetAttribute("AttributeName Here");
```