# Using getAttribute to get the class name of a webelement in Native context

Tags: android-layout, selenium, appium, nosuchelementexception

Went through the java docs of [getAttribute](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)). Couldn't understand the point mentioned as :

> Finally, the following commonly mis-capitalized attribute/property
>   names are evaluated as expected: "class" "readonly"

Could someone confirm if `webElement.getAttribute("class")` shall return the class name of the element or not?

**Edit** : On trying this myself

```
System.out.println("element " + webElement.getAttribute("class"));
```

I am getting

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException

**Note** : The element does exist on the screen as I can perform actions successfully on the element :

```
webElement.click(); //runs successfully
```

Code:

```
WebElement webElement = <findElement using some locator strategy>; 
System.out.println("element " + webElement.getAttribute("class"));
```

Comment: why don't you just try it?

Comment: Any reason for not testing it yourself?

Comment: @KjetilNordin : this is more to clarify/rectify the doc statement

Comment: @FlorentB. : edited the quesiton

Comment: I think the error is not from that line. Can you show us more code?

Comment: @Buaban : i have debugged, and evaluated the same line of code, its from the same line. + added more details

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException is thrown by findElement(). See details in https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException.html. Could you show us more code, please?

Comment: The question is a lot better now :). But as @Buaban said, we need to see some more context, in other words more code.

Comment: @KjetilNordin : i guess the entire code after creating the driver is this only `WebElement webElement = <findElement using some locator strategy>; System.out.println("element " + webElement.getAttribute("class"));`

Comment: @Buaban : actually you can give it a try on any WebElement you have on the native context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer to the problem was answered on GitHub in the issues list of appium/java-client by @SergeyTikhomirov. Simple solution to this is accessing the className property as following :

```
webElement.getAttribute("className")); //instead of 'class' as mentioned in the doc
```

*Method core implementation here* : [AndroidElement](https://github.com/appium/appium-android-bootstrap/blob/master/bootstrap/src/io/appium/android/bootstrap/AndroidElement.java#L182)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8936500/1203811), yes you are doing it right. Your `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException` is thrown because selenium can't find the element itself.

The sidenote you have posted, about `webElement.click()` actually working, is unfortunately not included in the code you have posted. Since it is not a part of the actual question, I leave this answer without adressing it.

Comment: the element is there, its just that appium throws the error with incorrect attribute as well

Comment: Oh well, you asked for confirmation if your code was correct. The only question in your post, was for a confirmation that `webElement.getAttribute("class")` was the correct way of doing it. I answered your question correctly, with a reference. If you didn't get the answer you wanted, it is because you didn't ask the question you wanted an answer for.

Comment: the answer was "No I was not doing it right" got the correct steps, have shared as an answer as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getStringAttribute(final String attr)
  throws UiObjectNotFoundException, NoAttributeFoundException {
String res;
if (attr.equals("name")) {
  res = getContentDesc();
  if (res.equals("")) {
    res = getText();
  }
} else if (attr.equals("contentDescription")) {
  res = getContentDesc();
} else if (attr.equals("text")) {
  res = getText();
} else if (attr.equals("className")) {
  res = getClassName();
} else if (attr.equals("resourceId")) {
  res = getResourceId();
} else {
  throw new NoAttributeFoundException(attr);
}
return res;
```

}